6 rooms 8 people Arrange Combination Problem with constraints
The 8 residents have to be filled in the 6 rooms such that 1 room has maximum of 1 resident and 2nd room has maximum of 2 residents and the other rooms don't have any limitations.
Here's my solution but it's wrong. I don't know the exact answer, but I know the answer begins with something like "120xxx" or "720xxx".
Case 1: Rooms 1 and 2 have 0 and 0 people each - "00" notation. Gives us 4^6 (each person can go into 6 rooms).
Case 2: "10" $8C1*4^7$
Case 3: "01" $8C1*4^7$
Case 4: "11" $8C2 * 4^6 * \frac{2!}{2}$
Case 5: "12" $\frac{3!}{1!*2!}*8C3*4^5$
Case 6: "02" $8C2*4^6$
But these give a total of 598016 which is not the answer. I am over-counting something?

Here's what you're missing:
In Case $00$, each of $8$ people can go into any of $4$ rooms (no one can go into the first two rooms), so this accounts for $4^8$ cases.
In Case $01$, you have $8$ choices for the second room and the remaining $7$ people have $4$ choices each, so this accounts for $8 \cdot 4^7$ cases.
In Case $02$, you have $\binom 82=28$ choices for the first room and the remaining $6$ people have $4$ choices each, so this accounts for $28 \cdot 4^6$ cases.
In Case $10$, you have $8$ choices for who can go into the first room.  The remaining $7$ people can go into into any of $4$ rooms, so this accounts for $8 \cdot 4^7$ cases.
In Case $11$, you have $8$ choices for the first room, then $7$ choices for the second room, and the remaining $6$ people have $4$ choices each, so this accounts for $56 \cdot 4^6$ cases.
Finally, in Case $12$, you have $8$ choices for the first room and $\binom 72=21$ choices for the second room.  The remaining $5$ people have $4$ choices each, so this accounts for $168 \cdot 4^5$ cases.
My calculator tells me these numbers sum to $843776$.

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{8}{a} \times \binom{8-a}{b}~$ choices for rooms 1 and 2 combined, where $~a \in \{0,1\},~$ and $~b \in \{0,1,2\}.~$
Then, there will be $~8 - (a+b)~$ people left, to be distributed into the $~4~$ remaining rooms, which can be done in $~4^{8 - (a+b)}~$ ways.
So, the desired computation is
$$\sum_{a=0}^1 \left\{ ~\sum_{b = 0}^2 ~\left[ ~\binom{8}{a} \times \binom{8-a}{b} \times 4^{8 - (a+b)} ~\right] ~\right\}. \tag1 $$
One approach to attacking the computations is to split the computations into two mutually exclusive cases, depending on whether $~a = 0,~$ or $~a = 1.$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~a = 0}$
The Case 1 computation is the sum of the terms
$$\left[ ~1 \times 4^8 ~\right] + \left[ ~8 \times 4^7 ~\right] + \left[ ~28 \times 4^6 ~\right] $$
$$= 4^6 \times [ ~16 + 32 + 28 ~] = 311296.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~a = 1}$
The Case 2 computation is the sum of the terms
$$8 \times \left\{ ~\left[ ~1 \times 4^7 ~\right] + \left[ ~7 \times 4^6 ~\right] + \left[ ~21 \times 4^5 ~\right] ~\right\} $$
$$= 8 \times 4^5 \times [ ~16 + 28 + 21 ~] = 532480.$$

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
$$311296 + 532480 = 843776.$$
